# How to open a configuration file through CAPL script

Tags: configuration, panel, capl, canoe

I have created a configuration that has a panel with options to open another configuration. When an option is selected from the panel, the corresponding configuration should open in Canoe. Is there any way to do this through CAPL scripting?
Are there any built-in functions available in CAPL?

Comment: Does this question relate to [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518491/how-to-open-a-specific-canoe-configuration-through-command-prompt-without-using)?

Answer (score 0):

CAPL API offers a way to start RT configurations, if they were previously download to an RT device. For instance:

> ```
> dword StandaloneConfigOpen(CHAR rtcfgFileName[], dword stopCurrentMeasurement, dword startNewMeasurement, dword returnToActiveConfig)
> ```
>
> Opens the RTCFG file with the given name as
> standalone configuration.
>
> - The given standalone configuration file must have been downloaded to the device before.
> - The command is only allowed while standalone mode is activated.
> - If standalone measurement is currently running the command is deferred until end of measurement (unless overwritten by another
>   subsequent open command).
> - If standalone measurement is not running but standalone mode is activated the file is loaded (and indicated in the Standalone Manager
>   GUI) but measurement is not started automatically.

If you need to execute more complex operations, or open a non-RT configuration, you'll have to rely on COM components or write your own routines.