# How to open a specific CANoe configuration through command prompt without using VB scripts?

Tags: cmd, configuration, capl, canoe

Is there any possibility to open a specific `CANoe` configuration through command prompt?

I tried opening a configuration like `sample.cfg` through command prompt by using the command:

```
C:\Users\Downloads\Sample>CANoe64 sample.cfg
```

With this command, I am able to start the `CANoe` application, but not with the specified configuration. `CANoe` application gets started with the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply mention

```
C:\Users\Downloads\Sample>sample.cfg
```

This will open the configuration in the registered version of CANoe.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer! I have two version of CANoe installed how to open configuration in a specific version from command prompt